# Is there a shorter \dag (\dagger)? Or how could we move it a bit, vertically?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, size, vertical-spacing

I'm experiencing a small glitch with index positions, because of the `\dag` (or `\dagger`) symbol.  Here's a MWE showing the small issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

Blabla
\begin{equation}
    \psi^{\dag} \, \psi_{\text{L}}^{\dag} \, \tensor{\psi}{_{\text{L}}} = -\: \psi_{\text{R}}^{\dag} \, \tensor{\psi}{_{\text{R}}} \,  \, \psi_{\text{R}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here's a preview showing the vertical spacing problem:

[image]

As you can see, the subscripts doesn't have the same vertical position everywhere.  I hate that!  Smashing any of the symbols (subscript or the dag symbol) isn't a good solution since it would produce some overlapping, or the symbols would touch (which is uglier!).

The problem is clearly the dag symbol, which is pretty long.  So is there a shorter dag symbol in LaTeX to replace the default one?  I searched and found none.

Take note that the tensor package gives the right position for subscripts (it's more consistent).  Removing the tensor "notation" would make the problem worst!

Maybe the best solution is to rise a bit the superscript symbol.  How can I do that to the `\dag` symbol (i.e rise it a bit)?

Answer (score 6):

Here, `\Dag` is made (by way of scaling) to take on the vertical footprint of a capital `X`.

Works across math styles.

See **ADDENDUM** for yet another alternative.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\Dag{\scalerel*{\dag}{X}}
\begin{document}

Blabla
\begin{equation}
    \psi^{\Dag} \, \psi_{\text{L}}^{\Dag} \, \tensor{\psi}{_{\text{L}}} = -\: \psi_{\text{R}}^{\Dag} \, \tensor{\psi}{_{\text{R}}} \,  \, \psi_{\text{R}}.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \scriptstyle
    \psi^{\Dag} \, \psi_{\text{L}}^{\Dag} \, \tensor{\psi}{_{\text{L}}} = -\: \psi_{\text{R}}^{\Dag} \, \tensor{\psi}{_{\text{R}}} \,  \, \psi_{\text{R}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One variation would be to replace, in the definition of `\Dag`, the `\scalerel*` with `\stretchrel*`.  This would change the vertical dimension of `\dag` only, while preserving the original horizontal dimension:

[image]

For comparison, here is the original `\dag`, followed by the scaled `\dag` and the stretched `\dag`.

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

After comments back and forth, the OP requested a version that shifts the normally-sized `\dag` upward, and uses no extra packages.  I created a version with `\raisebox` and `\mathchoice`, while using a trick (manually setting the depth of the particular `\dag`) to still keep it a little below the baseline:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\Dag{\mathchoice
  {\setbox0=\hbox{$\dag$}\dp0=.5\dp0\raisebox{\dp0}{\copy0}}
  {\setbox0=\hbox{$\dag$}\dp0=.5\dp0\raisebox{\dp0}{\copy0}}
  {\setbox0=\hbox{$\scriptstyle\dag$}\dp0=.5\dp0\raisebox{\dp0}{\copy0}}
  {\setbox0=\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\dag$}\dp0=.5\dp0\raisebox{\dp0}{\copy0}}
}
\begin{document}

Blabla
\begin{equation}
    \psi^{\Dag} \, \psi_{\text{L}}^{\Dag} \, \tensor{\psi}{_{\text{L}}} = -\: \psi_{\text{R}}^{\Dag} \, \tensor{\psi}{_{\text{R}}} \,  \, \psi_{\text{R}}.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \scriptstyle
    \psi^{\Dag} \, \psi_{\text{L}}^{\Dag} \, \tensor{\psi}{_{\text{L}}} = -\: \psi_{\text{R}}^{\Dag} \, \tensor{\psi}{_{\text{R}}} \,  \, \psi_{\text{R}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of the `X` on `\newcommand\Dag{\scalerel*{\dag}{X}}`? Thank you!

Comment: @manooooh `X` is the glyph the rescaled dagger inherits the dimensions of.

Comment: The second version appears better.  Is it possible to simply truncate the symbol (at the bottom), instead of stretching or compressing it?

Comment: @Cham One could use a `\clipbox` from the `trimclip` package to literally chop the bottom off.  However, the cut would have no roundness to it at all which, to my aesthetic sense, would be the ugliest possible alternative.

Comment: @Cham With `\usepackage{trimclip}`, try this: `\setbox0=\hbox{$\dagger$}
\clipbox {0pt \dp0 0pt -.5pt}{\copy0}` to see what I mean.  It also looks less like a dagger and more like a weird plus sign.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Cutting the symbol is ugly.  I'm wondering about other choices of symbols for the hermitian conjugate...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, what about rising the dag symbol a bit higher?  How could we do that?

Comment: @Cham Try: `\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand\Dag{\ThisStyle{\abovebaseline[0pt]{$\SavedStyle\dag$}}}`

Comment: This works, and looks better than compressing the dag symbol.  I may adopt that solution, but I don't like the idea to add a new package to my huge preamble!  I suggest that you add this solution as another answer to the original question.  Is there any other way in fixing the subscript, while moving the superscript?.

Comment: @Cham Here is a version without additional packages: `\newcommand\Dag{\mathchoice
{\setbox0=\hbox{$\dag$}\raisebox{\dp0}{\copy0}}
{\setbox0=\hbox{$\dag$}\raisebox{\dp0}{\copy0}}
{\setbox0=\hbox{$\scriptstyle\dag$}\raisebox{\dp0}{\copy0}}
{\setbox0=\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\dag$}\raisebox{\dp0}{\copy0}}
}`

Comment: Oh wow!  There's no way I could have found this by myself, without a special package!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, the command **\raisebox{2pt}{\scriptsize\dag}** (in place of a simple **\dag**) appears to do the trick.  What do you think?  Any way to improve this?  Any drawback?

Comment: @Cham The drawbacks are that 1) it could be font dependent, 2) it will be dependent on the current font size in the document, and 3) it will only work for a "normal" superscript, but will be perhaps unsightly if called as a superscript of a superscript.